How to add custom claims to User after or before login?
I use ASP.NET Core 8 project and Microsoft Identity.
I have to some user properties like UserId, FirstName, LastName, ImageName and etc. to user claims to use it in several place in the project.
I can get these properties from the database, but I need to add these as claims to user after login and use in pages, services and layouts.
Please help me.

After a lot of effort, I was able to solve the problem,
I tried to sign in with claims instead of PasswordsignIn:
       AppUser? user = await sm.UserManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(U=>U.UserName==Input.UserName);
   List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>()
   {
       new Claim( "UserId",user.UserId.ToString()),
       new Claim( "FullName",user.Title),
       new Claim( "Image",user.ImageName),
       new Claim( "ExpireDate",user.ExpireDate??""),
   };

   SignInResult result = default!;
    result = await  sm.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, Input.Password,true);
   if (result.Succeeded)
   {
       await sm.SignInWithClaimsAsync(user, Input.RememberMe, claims);              
   }


You can store claims in AspnetUserClaims table in database.

Those data has been stored in AspnetUsers table and can't save agin in another table.
